# Filter an array of objects based on another array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I want to filter this array of Object:

```
const testArray = [{
  id: 4,
  filters: ["Norway", "Sweden"]
}, {
  id: 2,
  filters :["Norway", "Sweden"]
}, {
  id: 3,
  filters:["Denmark", "Sweden"]
}]
```

with the filter

```
const myFilter=["Norway", "Sweden"]
```

However my code just returns []?
What I have tried so far:

```
const testArray = [{
  id: 4,
  filters: ["Norway", "Sweden"]
}, {
  id: 2,
  filters :["Norway", "Sweden"]
}, {
  id: 3,
  filters:["Denmark", "Sweden"]
}]
const myFilter=["Norway", "Sweden"]

console.log(testArray.filter(e=>e.filters===myFilter))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to test the *equality*+ of two arrays as follows:

```
const output = testArray.filter(
    e => e.filters.every(
        filter => myFilter.includes(filter)
    )
);
```

```js
const 
testArray = [{ id: 4, filters: ["Norway", "Sweden"] }, { id: 2, filters :["Norway", "Sweden"] }, { id: 3, filters:["Denmark", "Sweden"] }],
myFilter = ["Norway", "Sweden"],

output = testArray.filter(
    e => e.filters.every(
       filter => myFilter.includes(filter)
    )
);

console.log(output)
```

**NOTE**: `Array#every` as used here just confirms that every element of each array is in the other, **regardless of the order in which the elements appear**.